# Proper method to use referral data for a PHP based website

Tags: php

We manage an online enrollment site. Customers can ONLY enroll in our program if they come through an agent URL which currently has the format:

> www.site.com?Agent=AGENTID

While this approach works, it makes it very difficult for our agents to simply send out or 'tell' their URL to a potential customer.

I have tossed around the idea of making a subdomain redirect to the format above but our Media temple configuration requires major changes to the apache conf file which we are trying to avoid.

Similarly, I think we could just direct customers to www.site.com/agentid but run into the issue where /agentid will be treated as a page instead of an ID (and other times www.site.com/pagetitle may actually be used for a real page).

Anybody ever had a similar issue in the past? I'd be happy to hear any opinions for the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you create a subdomain only for referrals, and setup url rewriting on that subdomain?  Then it would not conflict with any pages on the main site.  Something like `agents.site.com/agentid`.

Comment: perhaps I am not thinking about it correctly but I think you would still have the last issue I was referring to above (agents.site.com/actual_page vs agents.site.com/aid123). One would look for an agent information (and fail, the first), the other would work but I would not want to recreate all files from the main directory into a subdirectory

Comment: @JM4: Using url rewriting, as discussed by @Zulan below, allows you to use agentid's and make agents.site.com/agentid actually internally request agents.site.com/agents.php?agentid=$agentid.

Comment: i think i have a better picture of what you were implying. I already use mod_rewrite rules as stated below by @zulan but the subdomain protects the rest of the pages as necessary and also gives us a better way to capture a "whoops, this doesnt exist"

Answer (score 2):

If you have `AllowOverwrite` and `mod_rewrite` activated, then you can create a redirect from www.site.com/agentid to your format without messing with the core apache conf, by placing a rewrite rule in a .htaccess in your main web directory.

I do not think there are any other solution without changing the apache configuration.

Comment: thanks but i discuss this in my initial question - i think the issue I face is that not even /XXXXX value will be an agent id, it could also be a normal page

Comment: is it possible to remove the www. a user may enter in a subdomain BUT KEEP any subdomain they may hve entered and use appropriately? For example: http://www.sub.domain.com redirects to http://sub.domain.com

Comment: @JM4 - rewrite rules are extremely powerful. You can specify regular expressions (if agentid is numeric). Using the `RewriteCond` directive you can also check for existing files/directories ('normal page'). Stripping a www is also possible. Is `AllowOverwrite` and `mod_rewrite` enabled for you? (assuming changes in the apache conf are impossible).

Comment: i can strip the www. from a primary domain but not from the subdomain (i.e. www.subdomain.site.com)

Comment: @JM4 - If you want to use www.sub.domain.com, you also need to setup the DNS configuration and the apache virtual hosts configuration for that.